# I cannot activate conda as www-data user

Tags: ubuntu, python, apache-httpd, webserver, datascience-anaconda

I am having some issues running a certain command. I'm running a LAMP-stack on Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS on a Linode.

In addition to this, I have also setup an [anaconda3](https://www.anaconda.com/) environment on the server as well. The environment needs to be activated in order to run a series of commands.

I want to run the command for **www-data** user:

```
conda activate bc
```

But as **www-data user**, the following is returned:

```
conda: command not found
```

When calling the command as the logged in user (in this case "**bc**"), the command executes perfectly.

I already tried running the command:

```
sudo -u www-data conda activate bc
```

But with no success, it returns the same (conda: command not found).

The path of anaconda3 has been in the home directory, however I have also tried reinstalling it, and changed the directory to usr/local with no luck.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `conda` in the PATH of apache?

Comment: As i turned out no, so thanks it helped me realize what i needed. what fixed the issue: sudo - u www-data path/to/python path/to/file.py   - where path to python has anaconda in the path.